# How to query difference between series with different tags in one measurement in InfluxDB？

Tags: influxdb

for example, temperature data from two different locations stored in one measurement, like

```
time                temperature               location
----                ----                              ----
1                     15                                 A
2                     20                                 B
3                     17                                 A
4                     18                                 B
```

How to calculate the difference between temperatures at A and B with querying?
i.e. expecting something like “SELECT a.temperature - b.temperature FROM measurement WHERE location = ‘A’ as a WHERE location = ‘B’ as b”

Thanks

Comment: you should be able to use kapacitor to calculate additional metric out of those two, if you can use kapacitor I can try helping you with writing it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subqueries](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#subqueries) for that e.g.

```
SELECT last("temp_a") - last("temp_b") FROM (
    SELECT "gauge" AS "temp_a" FROM "measurement" WHERE ("location"='A') AND $timeFilter
),(
    SELECT "gauge" AS "temp_b" FROM "measurement" WHERE ("location"='B') AND $timeFilter
) GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Influx query language does not support functions across measurements.